# Dagger2 - How to provide a new instance each time

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines

I'm new to Coroutines, I have read some documentation everywhere. I have a basic issue but I'm unable to resolve it... Basically, I'm calling a server to check authentication when the user click on the Connexion button (Easy).

**AuthenticationRepository**

```
@WorkerThread
suspend fun getAuthenticationToken(loginModel: LoginModel):TokenModel {
 return webService.getAuthenticationToken(loginModel)
}
```

**WebService**

```
suspend fun getToken(loginModel: LoginModel): TokenModel {
    val result = client.get<TokenModel>("https://app.com/rest/login") {
        url {
            parameters.append("login", loginModel.login)
            parameters.append("password", loginModel.password)
        }
    }.data
    client.close()
    return result
}
```

The first time I have the correct result.

The second time I click on the button..

```
Exception: kotlinx.coroutines.JobCancellationException: Parent job is Completed;
```

**EDIT**

Ok the issue came from the client.close() call. I'm using Dagger2 to provide the client, but the Ktor documentation is saying that the client needs to be closed after call.. How can I do that, I mean how can I provide a client each time?

**Client is provided like that**

```
@Provides
internal fun provideKtorHttpClient(): HttpClient {
    return HttpClient(Android) {
        install(JsonFeature) {
            serializer = KotlinxSerializer()
        }
    }
}
```

**In the webservice**

```
@Provides
internal fun provideKWebService(client: HttpClient): KWebServices = KWebServices(client)
```

**And finally in the repo**

```
@Provides
internal fun provideAuthenticationRemoteDataSource(ws: KWebServices): AuthenticationRemoteDataSource = AuthenticationRemoteDataSourceImpl(ws)
```

If you can help, thanks.

Comment: What is fun getAuthenticationToken(), You can sow code

Comment: I have put all the methods and classes, also, I have removed the try cathes and other unseful information.

Comment: I try to test, but I cannot reproduce this issue

Comment: Hum there is something weird, I have the same called (architecture, classes) but with a simple method, and it's working.... I'm digging.

Comment: I changed the all content, the problem came from the close method on the client. Now I'm looking to have a fresh instance each time but it's not working.